# actualizar campo foraneo laravel

Tags: php, laravel

buenas como podría hacer una actualización a una tabla que contiene varias llaves foraneas.

mi controlador en el actualizar esta de la siguiente manera:

```
   public function actualizar(Request $request, $id)
{
    HistorialMedico::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('index_historialMedico',$request->id_mascota)->with('mensaje','Registro creado');
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al editar yo llamo el nombre de la llave foranea en la vista y me da error al actualizar ya que no encuentra el valor del id de la llave foranea

```
<div class="col-4">
  <label for="id_responsable" class="">Responsable</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{old('id_responsable',$data->personalVet->nombre  ?? '')}}" readonly>  
</div>
```

Para solucionar momentáneamente, lo hago de la siguiente manera, con un imput hidden llamo el id de la llave foranea pero siento que no es correcto hacer esto:

```
<div class="col-4">
  <label for="id_responsable" class="">Responsable</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{old('id_responsable',$data->personalVet->nombre  ?? '')}}" readonly>  
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id_responsable" id="id_responsable" value="{{old('id_responsable',$data->id_responsable  ?? '')}}" readonly>  

</div>
```

hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo para evitar hacer uso de input hidden en la vista ?

PD: uso blade en las vistas apenas estoy aprendiendo laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no quieres guardar datos como `hidden` solo actualiza lo nescesario, aunque los `Stdclass` son tediosos de rellenar, controlas que campos actualizar directamente,

```
public function actualizar(Request $request, $id) {
    $h_med = HistorialMedico::findOrFail($id);
    $h_med->medico = $request->input('medico');
    $h_med->save();
    return redirect()->route('index_historialMedico',$h_med->id_mascota)->with('mensaje','Registro creado');
}
```

Comment: aah listo,seria como por así decirlo de la forma manual entonces, lo tedioso es que si mi tabla es muy grande(este no es el caso) seria codear mucho pero bueno muchas gracias por el aporte amigo.